# using an array as range parameter VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use CountIf excel function on VBA but I need some parameters that are not in the worksheet because are calculated in a sub procedure, for example

```
Dim myarray(1 To 10) As String
For i = 1 To 10
    myarray(i) = Cells(i, 3)
Next i

Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myarray, ">20")
```

But when I compile it, returns

`Compile error: Type mismatch`

I tried to get the first column using `Index` function  and use it as a parameter

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(myarray, 0), ">20")
```

But I get the following error

`Run-time error '424': Object required`

Is there a way to use the entire array as a parameter for this function?

Comment: I guess would have to loop or write a separate function to do the countif bit with a loop.

Comment: If you look into the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countif) the first parameter of `countIf` has to be a **range**. You will have to do your own `countif`. But don't forget to set values for `myarray` - because now it has no values.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you are receiving the error because the function is expecting a range and you are providing an array.  Below is a function that can do a similar operation to CountIf using arrays.

Note: I didn't include any error checking.

```
Private Function ArrayCountIf(ByRef Arr() As String, Criteria As String) As Integer
    ' Criteria Operations: "=", "<>", ">", "<", ">=", "<="

    ArrayCountIf = 0
    
    Dim oCounter As Integer
    For oCounter = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        If Application.Evaluate(Arr(oCounter) & Criteria) Then ArrayCountIf = ArrayCountIf + 1
    Next
End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim oArray(1 To 10) As String   'Will require error checking if values are not numeric

    'Populate array
    Dim oX As Integer
    For oX = 1 To 10
        oArray(oX) = oX + 2
    Next
    
    Dim oResult As Integer
    oResult = ArrayCountIf(oArray, ">5")
    
    MsgBox oResult
End Sub
```